# Parsing ipv4 addresses using boost-spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I would like to use boost::spirit for parsing ipv4 addresses. Here is what I have tried to do:

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>

struct Ipv4 { union { uint32_t as_int; uint8_t as_char[4]; } raw; };

Ipv4 make_ipv4(uint8_t i1, uint8_t i2, uint8_t i3, uint8_t i4) {
    Ipv4 ip;
    ip.raw.as_char[0] = i1; ip.raw.as_char[1] = i2;
    ip.raw.as_char[2] = i3; ip.raw.as_char[3] = i4;
    return ip;
}

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
qi::uint_parser<uint8_t, 10, 1, 3> octet;

struct Ipv4Address : qi::grammar<const char *, Ipv4()> {
    Ipv4Address() : Ipv4Address::base_type(start) {
        start = ( octet >> qi::lit('.') >> octet >> qi::lit('.') >>
                  octet >> qi::lit('.') >> octet
                ) [
                    //qi::_val = make_ipv4(1, 2, 3, 4) // working
                    qi::_val = make_ipv4(qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3, qi::_4) // compile error
                ]
        ;
    }
    qi::rule<const char *, Ipv4()> start;
} ipv4_address;

int main() {
    Ipv4 ip;
    const char * s = "1.2.3.4";
    bool r = qi::parse(s, s+strlen(s), ipv4_address, ip);
    std::cout << r << " " << (int)ip.raw.as_char[0] << "." <<
                             (int)ip.raw.as_char[1] << "." <<
                             (int)ip.raw.as_char[2] << "." <<
                             (int)ip.raw.as_char[3] << std::endl;
}
```

When compiling this I get the following compile error:

/tmp/ip.cxx: In constructor 'Ipv4Address::Ipv4Address()':
/tmp/ip.cxx:26:72: error: cannot convert 'const _1_type {aka const
boost::phoenix::actor >}' to 'uint8_t {aka
unsigned char}' for argument '1' to 'Ipv4 make_ipv4(uint8_t, uint8_t,
uint8_t, uint8_t)'

Any hints?

Is this the "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `bind` to lazily bind the function in the semantic action:

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
qi::uint_parser<uint8_t, 10, 1, 3> octet;

struct Ipv4Address : qi::grammar<const char *, Ipv4()> {
    Ipv4Address() : Ipv4Address::base_type(start) {
        start = ( octet >> qi::lit('.') >> octet >> qi::lit('.') >>
                  octet >> qi::lit('.') >> octet
                ) [
                    qi::_val = phx::bind(make_ipv4, qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3, qi::_4)
                ]
        ;
    }
    qi::rule<const char *, Ipv4()> start;
} ipv4_address;
```

Full sample:

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

struct Ipv4 { union { uint32_t as_int; uint8_t as_char[4]; } raw; };

Ipv4 make_ipv4(uint8_t i1, uint8_t i2, uint8_t i3, uint8_t i4) {
    Ipv4 ip;
    ip.raw.as_char[0] = i1; ip.raw.as_char[1] = i2;
    ip.raw.as_char[2] = i3; ip.raw.as_char[3] = i4;
    return ip;
}

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
qi::uint_parser<uint8_t, 10, 1, 3> octet;

struct Ipv4Address : qi::grammar<const char *, Ipv4()> {
    Ipv4Address() : Ipv4Address::base_type(start) {
        start = ( octet >> qi::lit('.') >> octet >> qi::lit('.') >>
                  octet >> qi::lit('.') >> octet
                ) [
                    qi::_val = phx::bind(make_ipv4, qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3, qi::_4)
                ]
        ;
    }
    qi::rule<const char *, Ipv4()> start;
} ipv4_address;

int main() {
    Ipv4 ip;
    const char * s = "1.2.3.4";
    bool r = qi::parse(s, s+strlen(s), ipv4_address, ip);
    std::cout << r << " " << (int)ip.raw.as_char[0] << "." <<
                             (int)ip.raw.as_char[1] << "." <<
                             (int)ip.raw.as_char[2] << "." <<
                             (int)ip.raw.as_char[3] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: how could I modify the excellent example with an optional port number.  I'm trying to write a CSV parser that accepts ip addresses with optinal port specifiers in the form x.y.z.w:nnnnn where nnnnn is a decimal in the range 1-65535.

Comment: `bool r = qi::parse(s, s+strlen(s), ipv4_address >> (":" > qi::uint_parser<uint16_t>() | qi::attr(0u)), ip, port);` would do nicely @johnco3